# Unexpected website behaviour on xampp; php define function

Tags: php, xampp

First time asking a question. PHP Amateur.

**Details:**
I am working on an eCommerce web project. The following is code contained in a file called `config.php` in a folder titled '`inc`'. Its purpose to define file and directory paths so that they need not be repeated when using the `incude()` function in other files.

**Problem:**
The CSS fails to render and also links break when hosted on XAMPP or the campus web server, but when hosted on a proper domain e.g www.myproject.com, it displays perfectly fine and works without any hiccups.

**Additional Information:**
The private campus web server takes the following address format `192.168.170.15/62631`, with the last section, '62631', being the student's folder on which the project is hosted.

```
  <?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
        session_start();
    }

    // site domain name with http
    defined("SITE_URL")
        || define("SITE_URL", "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);

    // directory separator
    defined("DS")
        || define("DS", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

    // root path
    defined("ROOT_PATH")
        || define("ROOT_PATH", realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . DS."..".DS));

    // classes folder
    defined("CLASSES_DIR")
        || define("CLASSES_DIR", "classes");

    // pages directory
    defined("PAGES_DIR")
        || define("PAGES_DIR", "pages");

    // modules folder
    defined("MOD_DIR")
        || define("MOD_DIR", "mod");

    // inc folder
    defined("INC_DIR")
        || define("INC_DIR", "inc");

    // templates folder
    defined("TEMPLATE_DIR")
        || define("TEMPLATE_DIR", "template");

    // emails path
    defined("EMAILS_PATH")
        || define("EMAILS_PATH", ROOT_PATH.DS."emails");

    // catalogue images path
    defined("CATALOGUE_PATH")
        || define("CATALOGUE_PATH", ROOT_PATH.DS."media".DS."catalogue");

    // add all above directories to the include path
    set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
        realpath(ROOT_PATH.DS.CLASSES_DIR),
        realpath(ROOT_PATH.DS.PAGES_DIR),
        realpath(ROOT_PATH.DS.MOD_DIR),
        realpath(ROOT_PATH.DS.INC_DIR),
        realpath(ROOT_PATH.DS.TEMPLATE_DIR),
        get_include_path()
    )));
```

**Some additional information:**
There is only one other file in the '`inc`' folder named `autoload.php`. It interacts with the `config.php` script as follows:

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');

function __autoload($class_name) {
    $class = explode("_", $class_name);
    $path = implode("/", $class).".php";
    require_once($path);
}
```

**Another instance that's similar to the xampp and campus server problem:**
The files are hosted in a sub-domain that points to a a folder named 'project'. When loaded as project.site.com it works fine, but when site.com/project is typed in, the same problem is encountered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be don't need this answer anymore, but I am answering.

I am having the same problem. So I tried again and again, then found the problem and solve. Everything is right in the code except

```
require_once('config.php');
```

Please replace that with

```
require_once('inc/config.php');
```

Now you are done. Because it wasn't getting the config file.

As the function by which you can call only the file name instead of additional  path directory is defined in the config file. So, it will not work for it's own.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, problem is in `defined("SITE_URL")`. Echo the `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` & see, you will get only 192.168.170.15 not 62631.

```
defined("SITE_URL")
       || define("SITE_URL", "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/62631");
```

Comment: I've just tried that. Still getting the same problem. Links broken (404 Errors), CSS still does not render.

Comment: Will you post your sample CSS link which is in <head> tag?

Comment: `<link href="/css/core.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Comment: When I echo `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` I get 'localhost' as a result.